# Installation of YouTube plugin is CKEdior

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need integrate YouTube plugin into CKEditor. I have downloaded this plugin http://sourceforge.net/projects/ckeditoryoutube/ Now I tried make it functionally. I try this code, but it doesn't work.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
    // instance, using default configuration.
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'text',
        {
            extraPlugins : 'youtube',
            toolbar :
            [
                [ 'Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink' ],
                [ 'youtube' ]
            ]
        });
//]]>
</script>
```

Have you got somebody any idea?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@David Holada : First you have to analyse how the CKEditor is implemented in your project and then try to add the Plugin.js in the youtube folder to appropriate place in your project.

First try to analyse what the plugin does by looking at the youtube/dialogs/youtube.js.

Secondly you can go throgh this [a CKEditor_3.x Tutorials](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials).

Hope this helps.